# Regex to convert CamelCase identifiers to UPPER_CASE

Tags: regex

I have following lines

```
GetAuthServerList
GetAuthServerConfiguration
AddAuthServer
```

I have to convert them to

```
GET_AUTH_SERVER_LIST
GET_AUTH_SERVER_CONFIGURATION
```

and so on.

I tried to replace `([A-Z][a-z]+)` with `\1_` in sublime text editor, but it is replacing the last search also. How do I skip the last match of the line?

Can I simultaneously insert `_` and make the lower case to uppercase in one replacement?

Comment: just a simple replacement in sublime 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what :  `([a-z])([A-Z])`
Replace with:  `\1_\2`
You  have an option to convert selection to uppercase in sublime text.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have sublime installed, but try this:

```
[a-z](?=[A-Z])
```

replace it with `&_`

or

```
   replace ([a-z])(?=[A-Z])  with \1_
```

in **vim** it would be:

```
%s/\v[a-z]([A-Z])@=/&_/g
```

Answer (score 0):

A little modification using negative lookahead should help

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)(?!$)
```

Comment: It is matching the last word of line but skipping the last alphabet, so it would insert underscore at second last position.